# textarea preview like stackoverflow have

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `textarea`, I created a preview div which only displays the text, but I want the text to have background color of grey when the sentence is between `` to display codes.

```
<textarea onChange={handleChange}></textarea>
```

I have a div which contains `pre` and `code` block.

```
<div>
 <pre>{preview}</pre>
 <code>{code}</code>
</div>
```

my `handleChange` function is:

```
const handleChange = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    setDescription(e.target.value)
    setPreview(e.target.value);

    if (e.key === '`'){
      setCode(e.target.value)
    }

}
```

Here, Code and preview are defined using `useState`

```
const [preview, setPreview] = useState("");
const [code, setCode] = useState("");
```

Is there any way I can accomplish it?

Comment: Applying `e.target.value` to `setCode` writes all the text in textarea to `code`.

Comment: @newdeepji but I just want text between `` to be written any idea how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably consider using some library for this that handles all edge cases.

But for learning purposes you can refer to the snippet below, I've split the text by `` ` `` and wrapped all the odd index items in `code`.

When you split the string `` "type `code` here" ``, you get this array `["type", "code", "here"]` and if you observe the contents wrapped inside `` ` `` will always be at an odd index. So, I've mapped over the array and wrapped all odd index items within `code`. *Try spitting more such strings and you'll get more clarity on this.*

```js
function App() {
  const [content, setContent] = React.useState("Type `code` here");

  return (
    <div>
      <textarea
        value={content}
        onChange={({ target }) => setContent(target.value)}
      ></textarea>
      <p>
        {content
          .split("`")
          .map((c, i) => (i & 1 ? <code key={i}>{c}</code> : c))}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```css
code {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  border-radius: 0.15rem;
}

textarea {
  width: 60ch;
  height: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: what is the logic behind that map function, why are we checking for `odd` and `even` there.

Comment: I've updated my code with some explanation, please check.